# awk, how to remove a big string with special chars?

Tags: awk

I want to remove a big string with a lot o special chars. With `sed` I failed even using `''` and `""` to quote special chars.

So I tried `awk`

```
gawk '{gsub("[VERYLGONGSTIRNGKKXquQX4wbbEKW8gUilRyw/withalotofspecialchars/ABUJBJHHF848488484.....end]", "");print}' file.txt
```

The problem is that it removes the string but substitutes it with a `-`.

My goal is to preserve the rest of the file, for example

```
file.txt
string1
string2
VERYLGONGSTIRNGKKXquQX4wbbEKW8gUilRyw/withalotofspecialchars/ABUJBJHHF848488484.....end
OTHERLONGSTRINGWHICHIWANTTOPRESERVE...
string4
```

becomes..

```
string1
string2
OTHERLONGSTRINGWHICHIWANTTOPRESERVE...
string4
```

How to do this?

Comment: Is it the only long string? The answer I would write is `sed '/.\{80\}/d' file`, wich deletes the string that is longer than 80 characters (as example). Does it work for you?

Comment: The pattern `[whateverstuffhere]` really only matches a single character (one from the `[...]` set). Also, `gsub()` (and `sub()`) modifies a line, but does not remove it. Why can't you just do `grep -v -x -F 'your string here'`?

Comment: no is not the only string with 80 chars

Comment: Could you give a concrete, real example of the input  file?

Comment: See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for the root of your sed problem, and [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for how to pass a literal string to awk so you can use literal string functions instead of regexps and backreferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell's [quoted heredocs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) are a handy mechanism for dealing with quoting/escaping hell:

```bsh
string_with_quotes=$(cat << 'END'
long string with 'single quotes' and "double quotes" and *[arbitrary $special !characters.
END
)
```

And awk's `-v` option passes a shell variable into an awk variable. Use string equality instead of regular expression matching.

```bsh
awk -v target="$string_with_quotes" '$0 != target' file
```

---

As Ed comments, `-v` can be problematic <sup>[other techniques]</sup>.

```bsh
special='foo\tbar\rqux'
awk -v target="$special" 'BEGIN {print target}'
```

```
qux   bar
```

To pass the string via the environment

```bsh
special='foo\tbar\rqux'
export special
awk 'BEGIN {print ENVIRON["string_with_quotes"]}'
```

```
foo\tbar\rqux
```

And, apropos to your question

```bsh
export special=3
seq 5 | awk '$0 != ENVIRON["special"]'
```

```
1
2
4
5
```

---

<sup>[other techniques]</sup>:
Since the issue is whether we want awk to interpret escape sequences or not (are the 2 characters <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> supposed to be seen in awk as (i) a 2 character string or (ii) a single tab character).
As demonstrated, using the environment to pass data forces awk to *not* interpret escape suequences.
We can also use bash techniques to do the same thing, but it's far less elegant:

```bsh
# not exported
special='foo\tbar\rqux'

awk -v target="${special//\\/\\\\}" 'BEGIN {print target}'
# or
awk -v target="$(printf '%q' "$special")" 'BEGIN {print target}'
```

Comment: `-v` would interpret escape sequences though and, e.g. turn `\t` into a literal tab character. You need to use `ENVIRON[]` or `ARGV[]` or read input to pass a string to awk unaltered.

Comment: Unlike when using `BEGIN {print ENVIRON["special"]}`, the `export` in `export special='foo\tbar\rqux'` seems to be superfluous if you pass the value with `-v`...   No matter, interesting answer. Tx.

Comment: @Cbhihe `awk -v var="$foo"` is accessing the value of `$foo` in the current shell that's calling awk while `awk '{ENVIRON["foo"]}'` is accessing it in the subshell that's running awk, hence the need for it to be exported in that case or just referenced on the command-line, e.g. you don't need to export it (which is usually best avoided) if you do `foo="$foo" awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["foo"]}'` all on one line.

Comment: @Cbhihe, the issue we're playing with here is awk interpreting the two characters `\ ` `t` as a tab character. If that is what you want, then the `-v` option is fine. If you want awk to see the string absolutely verbatim, going through the environment is a good approach.

Comment: @EdMorton, and Glenn: precisely ! All I was saying was, no matter what the objective is, `export`'ing `special` in `export special='foo\tbar\rqux'; awk -v target="$special" 'BEGIN {print target}'` seems superfluous. It does not modify the output, if output is what counts, and just encumbers the environment with a new variable. The logic you both highlight is naturally just fine. No prob.

Comment: Yes certainly, in that case `export` is not required.